# Backing NTFS in linux

Tags: backup, ntfs

Is partimage ready for NTFS volumes? It said that support for NTFS is 
experimental, is that safe for production ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good results with [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) which uses [partclone](http://partclone.org/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [website](http://www.partimage.org/Changelog), partimage hasn't been updated since mid-2010 and the site itself hasn't been modified in a long time. I wouldn't trust it with anything I'd mind losing.